# Request factory generic method properties

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

Is it possible to use generics in Request methods? Or if not how to workaround this problem?

Lets say that I would like to implement pagination. So in my request interface I've got such method:

```
public List<UserProxy> getUserList(int offset, int limit);
```

but the list returns only limited data. For pagination implementation I need also total elements. In RPC style I would use Result object:

```
public MyResultObject<User> getUserList(int offset, int limit)
```

where in MyResultObject I would store List and totalCount as property. Unfortunately in RF I'm not able to that. Also in GWT-RPC I could use command pattern and retrive list from one method and totalcount from another one in a single request.

How to get totalcount with element list in the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a MyResultObjectProxy (admittedly specialized for the UserProxy), or you can make your two requests (list and total count) in the same HTTP batch request:

```java
MyContext ctx = factory.context();
ctx.getUserList(offset, limit).to(new Receiver<List<UserProxy>>() { … });
ctx.getUserTotalCount().to(new Receiver<Integer>() { … });
ctx.fire();
```

Since GWT 2.4, RF supports polymorphism, so maybe you could use a MyResultObjectProxy that's not specialized to a specific EntityProxy (or Value Proxy), though I'm really not sure it'd actually work.

Comment: So your firs aproach works, but I would have to write MyResultObjectProx for each entity that I would like to display in pagination view.<br/>
The second one in my opinion is the best one, but I need to write two receivers and synchronize them together. In fact I wrote ReceiverManager which do that, but in my opinion it is still awkward method with boilerplate code.

Comment: Third option is the best to write not specialized to a a specific Proxy but it doesn't work as proxies don't accept generics or Object as list elements. Any other ideas?

Comment: Re. third option: even if you simply use `List<EntityProxy>`? or maybe make all your entity proxies extend the same base interface, and use that interface. You'd have to add casts, for sure, but that's still less boilerplate code and a lighter compiled code.

Comment: It almost works. I've got following proxy: `@ProxyFor(value=MyResult.class)
public interface MyResultProxy extends ValueProxy{

    public List<ValueProxy> getList();

    public Integer getTotalCount();
}` but on the client I'm getting ValueProxy and I'm not able to cast it into UserProxy.

Comment: Anyway thank you for the hint with batching. Probably till bug http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6234 will be fixed it's it's the only working solution. Thank you Thomas.